# Enzyme test if onClick pushRoute redirects to other page

Tags: testing, enzyme

Good day.
I am coding some tests and i am not really sure how to check if a pushRoute function has actually sent me to the page i want.

Here's an edited code of the component and the test i am trying to perform.

Component:

```
  redirectToRoute= () => {
      this.props.pushRoute('/some/route')     
   }

<SomeComponent
    title="Some Title"
    value={value}
    onClick={() => this.redirectToRoute()}
 />
```

Test:

```
it('Should redirect to route', () => {
    const pushRoute = jest.fn();
    const wrapper = setup({ pushRoute });

    wrapper.instance().redirectToRoute();
    expect(pushRoute).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
});
```

In here i can test if onClick has been called but i don't now how to checkout if it redirects to the route i want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also check that `pushRoute` was called with the expected route:

```js
it('Should redirect to route', () => {
  const pushRoute = jest.fn();
  const wrapper = setup({ pushRoute });

  wrapper.instance().redirectToRoute();
  expect(pushRoute).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);  // Success!
  expect(pushRoute).toHaveBeenCalledWith('/some/route');  // Success!
});
```

That is all that needs to be tested for this component since it is not responsible for doing the redirecting, it just calls the `pushRoute` property that it is given.

Comment: this worked. i just had to change a little bit to fit into my code.